# Selecting nested lists

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a navbar that contains a menu nested 3 times. So I have a div with `id="navbar"`, which contains an `ul`, that has a `li` item with `id="menu"`, that contains another `ul`, that contains more `li` items. Now I want to target every `ul` seperately, to add some JS code to it, make the first layer display in a row and so forth. So far I've only managed to target the first level, and the third one, but haven't been able to change properties of the second one. Somehow `#navbar ul li` goes to the first one, but `#navbar ul li ul li` targets the third. What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<div id="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">IJS</a></li>
        <li class="ion-navicon-round" id="menu"></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">knjižnica</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">zaloga</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">novi izvodi tiskanih revij</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">elektronske revije</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">katalog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">baze podatkov</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">storitve</a>
                    <ul>        
                        <li><a href="#">medknjižnična izposoja</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">fotokopirnica</a></li>              
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        <li><a href="#">ENG</a></li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#navbar {
    background-color: #913D88;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

#navbar ul li {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#navbar ul li a:link, #navbar ul li a:visited {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navbar ul li ul li {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Try using the child selector > so it would be '#navbar > ul > li  > ul > li'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small mistake. Your second level `ul` are outside of `li` elements instead of inside.

The problem is there in the following code.

```
  <li class="ion-navicon-round" id="menu"></li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">knjižnica</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">zaloga</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">novi izvodi tiskanih revij</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">elektronske revije</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">katalog</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">baze podatkov</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">storitve</a>
                            <ul>        
                                <li><a href="#">medknjižnična izposoja</a>   </li>
                                <li><a href="#">fotokopirnica</a></li>              
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

Should be like this.

```
  <li class="ion-navicon-round" id="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">knjižnica</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">zaloga</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">novi izvodi tiskanih revij</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">elektronske revije</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">katalog</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">baze podatkov</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">storitve</a>
                            <ul>        
                                <li><a href="#">medknjižnična izposoja</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">fotokopirnica</a></li>              
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
     </li>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/u0jzvLf3/)

Answer (score 1):

you have an error in your syntax.

the second "ul" is *not* in an li, because you close the li before it.
so try

```
#navbar ul ul li {
    background-color: #ffff00;
}
```